# How to rewrite URL in IIS using regex

Tags: regex, url, iis, url-rewrite-module

I have IIS and want to configure URL rewriting.
How I can to rewrite any type of URL like:

http://anydomain.com/subfolder/page.html

to

http://anydomain.com/mysubfolder/subfolder/page.html

So only what I need is to add just one subfolder name into URL after host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/nB3oL3/5) for split url

```
^(https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/)(.*)$
```

and [How-To](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns) iis url rewrite. Your pattern must look like that

```
{R:1}mysubfolder/{R:2}
```